# We want hats, right?

Tags: discussion, community, site-promotion

SE is planning to run another "[dash for hats](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/12/gaming-holiday-promotion-hat-dash/)!"-style promotion this year, but this time for all the sites. Here's some example hats from last year:

[image: hats]

Now, it's **totally opt-in**, both on a per-site and per-user basis, so I just want to confirm that there's positive energy in the community behind this before moving too much further ahead.

I think participating in the awesome hat promotion thing would be a lot of fun for the community, and could provide a wider opportunity to engage community members even more deeply and develop even more great content.

But it would help if we opt-in! If you think the community could benefit from participation, just **act on this meta post** -- vote it up, answer in the affirmative, provide positive comments.

Keep in mind that even if we participate as a community, it would still be optional for individual users -- you'll just have to click an "I hate Hats!" link to opt out :)

Please let us know what you think!

Comment: Yes! Hats! Hats for everyone!

Comment: ...can we get Plato-beards? :)

Comment: FREE HAT! 
It's time we raised awareness for infant-on-adult violence.

Comment: Neither hats nor Plato beards this year? ;-)

Comment: I didn't understand the hats last year when I joined, but now I think they are a great idea.