# Is there hats data from previous years?

Tags: discussion

I got a new hat today and put it on and started looking around on the Winter Bash 2018 pages.  There's more there than I realized.

There is a home page where (if you log in) you can see your hats plus all the hats available to Philosophy SE: https://winterbash2018.stackexchange.com/

There's an FAQ page: https://winterbash2018.stackexchange.com/faq

There is a leaderboard page: https://winterbash2018.stackexchange.com/leaderboard

Philosophy is a ways down on that leaderboard page, but here is the specific page for Philosophy SE: https://winterbash2018.stackexchange.com/leaderboard/philosophy.stackexchange.com

Confused and I are in the #1 place for the most hats (so far on Philosophy SE): 8.

All this ends in a few hours and that brings me to my question:'

**Is there a place to see the statistics on hats from previous years?**

Here is an earlier discussion of hats: [We want hats, right?](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/453/29944)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems not. From [How to get my previous Hat on Winter Bash?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/304840/how-to-get-my-previous-hat-on-winter-bash) on [Meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/):

> The hat page is only for the year, and you cannot wear or see previous years hats